# INSERT INTO command doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one outer cursor and one inner cursor also have two tables to work with. Now with the outer cursor i'm making new columns in the table 1 and naming them by the values from the table two, and that works just fine. Problem is with the inner cursor witch i used to insert the values into those new columns from one specific column from another table. This seams not to work, but what confusing me is that i do not get any error messages. Now i hope you understand what i'm trying to do, here is the code so comment for more description about the problem :

```
DECLARE @rbr_param  nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @vrednost nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @cName nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar (255)



DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT rbr_param FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna ORDER BY   rbr_param
OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @rbr_param
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

SET @cName = 'P_'+@rbr_param+'_P'
EXEC('ALTER TABLE dbo.Parametri ADD ' + @cName + ' nvarchar(255)')

    DECLARE vrd CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT vrednost FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna
    OPEN vrd
        FETCH NEXT FROM vrd
        INTO @vrednost
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO dbo.Parametri'+(@cName)+ ' SELECT vrednost    FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna WHERE vrednost = '+@vrednost+ ' AND rbr_param = '+@rbr_param

        if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where   table_name = 'dbo.Parametri' and column_name = '@cName')
        begin
        exec(@sql)
        end
        FETCH NEXT FROM vrd
        INTO @vrednost
        END --end vrd
        CLOSE vrd
        DEALLOCATE vrd

FETCH NEXT FROM curs
INTO @rbr_param

END
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Comment: try wrapping () around the `SELECT` statement in your `INSERT`. `INSERT INTO dbo.Parametri'+(@cName)+ ' (SELECT vrednost    FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna WHERE vrednost = '+@vrednost+ ' AND rbr_param = '+@rbr_param+')'`

Comment: I tried but still the same... no errors but no inserts neither

Comment: This is just about the worst possible way to approach this: it seems to have almost no Relational concepts at all.  Even if the procedure worked, I am close to certain that what it does is not something that you could possibly want (unless the data design is far worse than even I thought).

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems here:

```
if exists ( select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     where  table_name = 'dbo.Parametri'
      and column_name = '@cName'
)
```

(1) This view will never have `table_name` = schema name *and* table name.

(2) You have enclosed your variable name in single quotes for some reason.

For both of these reasons, your `IF` condition will never return true.

Try:

```
IF EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
      WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Parametri')
      AND name = @cName
)
```

([And here is why I prefer catalog views over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).)

Also this double-nested cursor thing seems quite inefficient and a lot more code than necessary to achieve what I think you're trying to do. How about something like this instead:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'ALTER TABLE dbo.Parametri ADD ' 
   + QUOTENAME('P_' + rbr_param + '_P') + ' NVARCHAR(255);'
  FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna GROUP BY rbr_param;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SET @sql = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N'INSERT dbo.Parametri('+QUOTENAME('P_' + rbr_param + '_P')+ ') 
   SELECT vrednost 
   FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna WHERE rbr_param = ''' + rbr_param + '''
     GROUP BY vrednost;'
   FROM dbo.parametri_pomocna
    GROUP BY rbr_param;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Ok seems like i have some errors now... i'll try to make this works. Thanks for the help